# Object is not perpendicular to the axis

Tags: python, objects, coordinates, axis

I have a model which is created by 3d reconstruction and the human is connected to the floor. I found that the human body is not in the same direction as the z-axis, as figure 1 shows. What I want is to make the model, through python scripts, in the direction that the figure 2 shows.
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, rotate it in Edit mode? But do his feet need to stick to the oblique ground?

Comment: Thanks, rotation is a way, but I'm looking for a way that can be achieved through python scripts.

Comment: for a python script, you'll need to have something that tells you what is "vertical" considering a particular object... from what can you start in that matter?

Comment: @moonboots And yes, his feet stick to the oblique ground. After rotation, I will cut the ground based on other techniques that I already figured out.

Comment: @lemon do you think geometry nodes like vertices and edges can help?

Comment: that could be a bounding box minimization in some axis. but for that, you need to know, for instance, that the original floor is horizontal (as that's not the general case).

Comment: @lemon that could be difficult, 'cause the original floor is not horizontal, just like what the picture shows.

Comment: ok, but you want it to be, right? Maybe a dichotomy for angles between 0 and 90°?

Comment: @lemon sorry, I don't understand what you said.

Comment: ok, to be sure of what we are talking about, could you edit your question by adding a picture of the result you want?

Comment: @lemon Thanks, I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use "Mesh: 3D print toolbox" addon (which is in Blender's distribution).

It has a function that rotates the entire object so that the selected faces lie on average along the X/Y plane.

[image]

You can call this addon operation or refer to its Python code to embed and use it in your own code.

This code can be [found here](https://github.com/sobotka/blender-addons/blob/7d80f2f97161fc8e353a657b179b9aa1f8e5280b/object_print3d_utils/operators.py#L731C26-L731C26).

In short, it calculates the mean face normals ponderated by face areas and calculates the rotational difference to the Z axis in world coordinates. This gives the wanted rotation which is used to rotate the object back to the horizontal.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it!